# Activity indicator not animating even after writing [activityIndicator startAnimating]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried searching , but find no clue . Also I relied to drop a single button and when i tried animating activity indicator in that button's function , it was animating .

As soon as I write a code in the button's method , the activity indicator docent work.

Please suggest improvements

```
NSString *home= @"http://kivihealth.com/api/";
NSString *apiType = @"patientapi/";
NSString *apiMethod = @"authenticatepatient?";

NSMutableString *url  = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:home];
[url appendString:apiType];
[url appendString:apiMethod];

NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",self.emailInputted.text,self.PasswordInputted.text];
[url appendString:temp];

// PROBLEM -  NOT WORKING
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSURL *finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];
NSError *error;

[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

if(data == nil)
{
    UIAlertView *invalidDetailsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SIGN IN FAILED" message:@"Netwok error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [invalidDetailsAlert show];
}
else
{
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary *da = json[@"data"];
    NSString *message = da[@"message"];
    if ([message isEqualToString:@"Valid Details"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Inside Valid");
        //NSLog(@"%@",da);
        Patient *defaultPatient = [[Patient alloc]init];
        defaultPatient=[defaultPatient initWithRegId:da[@"regid"] city:da[@"city"] area:da[@"area"] mobile:da[@"mobile"] landline:da[@"landline"] dob:da[@"dob"] sex:da[@"sex"] name:da[@"name"] chronicDiseases:da[@"chronicdiseases"] aboutHealth:da[@"abouthealth"] email:self.emailInputted.text];
        [defaultPatient saveAsDefaultUser];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        AfterLoginViewController *afterLoginViewController = (AfterLoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AfterLoginViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:afterLoginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *invalidDetailsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SIGN IN FAILED" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [invalidDetailsAlert show];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried to drop a button other than login button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT a lot has changed since I originally posted this one**

The execution of an animation has to happen on the main thread while the process of loading things has to happen on another thread.

If you want to run everything on one thread, the main thread (where the UI is running on) gets blocked as long as the execution/run-loop is not complete.

**Swift 3**

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

// put the activityIndicator to use somewhere or use an IBOutlet

activityIndicator.startAnimating()

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    // do your stuff

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not really apply for network calls anymore since the nature of that has moved into `URLSession` it would look something like this:

```
let url = URL(with: "http://google.com")
let urlRequest = URLRequest(string: url)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    // do some parsing and verify/validate your response is not an error
    // eg the response.statusCode could be helpful to see if an error occurred 
    ...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // report back to ViewController
    }
}
task.resume()
```

**OLD SOLUTION:**

this is an example of what you could do instead

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];
    NSError *error;
    // do stuff
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        // UI Updates
    });
});
```

In my eyes the whole code should look different, try using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) to better organise your networking code. Read the documentation on the page and consider using [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org)

Comment: @KaranSingh sure - if you like the answer, I would appreciate if you could accept it or upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

[self.activityIndicator startAnimating] used the method viewDidLoad and [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating] use it in the end method.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some kind of start/completion logic in order to use activity indicator, basically what you're doing right now is start animation and ending it right after that, without any kind of delay.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];` from the main thread, this also blocks the UI and any animation. This should really not be called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using an `activityIndicator` on a `customCell` for a `tableView` and I had the same problem, even after writting down `activityIndicator.startAnimating()` the loading was not moving.

After hours of trying i came out with a solution.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
       activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Just use the method `prepareForReuse()` show when you reuse the `customCell` the `activityIndicator` is animating